# Is there a way for my aplication to detect beacons in Powerapps?

Tags: ibeacon, beacon, powerapps, eddystone

I am trying to create an app using Powerapps where I need to interact with beacons ( their brand is Minew).
I want to start with something basic, like get a notification when the beacon is detected. Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

As @davidgyoung mentioned, the simple answer is no. The most complex answer is it depends on whether the beacon can be exposed to the world (Internet) as a [custom connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/connectors/custom-connectors/) - there's currently no way to use bluetooth, for example, for communication between PowerApps and the external world.

If the beacon is Internet-connected, then it may be possible to use whatever the beacon is detecting (time, temperature, etc.) as a trigger in the custom connector. Once that is done, then you could create a [flow](https://flow.microsoft.com/) that is started based on that trigger, and the flow can send a push notification to PowerApps (or the flow can store the notification in some data source, and PowerApps can poll for new notifications). You'll also need to manage subscriptions (which apps / users can listen to which notifications from the beacons).

So, this may technically be possible (depending on the capability of the Minew, which I don't know), but it will involve some work to get it done.

Comment: This is helpful info.  The most popular Minew beacon models are simple bluetooth transmitter devices that have no network connectivity, so it certainly would not be possible to get notified of a beacon detection event over a network interface.  What I don't know is whether PowerApps has any ability to provide local native connectors that run exclusively on the device.  If PowerApps provides this ability, then it may in theory be possible to make this happen.  @carosfigueira, can you confirm this either way?

Comment: You're correct. Currently connectors used within PowerApps are hosted in Azure (or hosted on-premises via gateways) but they always go via a network interface. If you really, really, really want to get this scenario working, you could possibly have a separate device that would connect via bluetooth to the Minew, and then broadcast it to the Internet, but at this point (or even before that) I wonder if the complexity is worth it.

Comment: @carlosfigueira the MINEW beacons I am using have a router that recieves their signal and I can access them online. If I build a simple azure web app that connects to it and registers the beacons in my database would that work?

Comment: @MigthyMoron yes, that may work; if you can write the beacon signals to a database, then your app should be able to get that database to poll for data from the beacon.

Answer (score 2):

It's always hard to authoritatively say something is not possible (somebody can always build a way later and then prove you wrong!) but in years of professional beacon work, I have never heard of anybody using the Powerapps platform to build beacon apps.  While **I highly suspect that "no" is the simple answer to this question**, I would welcome anyone knowing otherwise to provide another answer.

Comment: Well from what I have been reading I think "no" really is the answer.
Too bad